# How to set `minimum` file size for upload

Tags: angular, ng2-file-upload

I am using [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) for file upload requirement with my angular application. in this directive i can able to set the `maxFileSize` - but the thing is, there is a way to upload just empty file. so i am looking for a solution to prevent the empty file upload.

is there a way to test it and throw error? or can i set the min size for upload?

here is my config:

```
this.uploader = new FileUploader({
  isHTML5: true,
  maxFileSize: maxFileSize, //how to set min size?
  queueLimit: queueLimit,
  autoUpload: false,
  headers: [{name: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/octet-stream'}]
});
```

Comment: there is no minsize attribute in ng2-file-upload. You can create your own fork and refer it from your own git hub or you can request the author to add it for you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set a minimum, just do

```
if(this.uploader.size < 0){
// Let the user know
}
```

Comment: Understood, but how to trigger the error function, from this condition? is it possible?

Comment: @user2024080 That's up to you and how you want to handle it